# Change auto_zooming parameter at runtime on cefpython

Tags: python, wxpython, zooming, embedded-browser, cefpython

I have a Flask app that render some page on localhost:3000. To display correctly this page on every computer i use chromium browser (Basically WXpython example from cefpython3 with minor changes: https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython/blob/master/examples/wxpython.py). However on some computers that have a different resolution/zoom level i have to re-run the code with a different value of parameter 'auto_zooming' in order to display correctly the page:

```
...

zoom = '0'
settings = {'debug': False, 'auto_zooming': zoom} 
cef.Initialize(settings=settings)

...
```

My question is: There is any way to change the zoom level of Cefpython browser without have to rerun the code everytime i want to change the zoom? I was thinking on something like 'ctrl - +' or 'ctrl - -'.

Thanks in advance, 
Ricardo

Answer (score 1):

Can't you detect zoom level before initializing CEF?

The `auto_zooming` option will call `SetBrowserDpiSettings` C++ function. It sets zoom level constantly in a 50 ms timer. You can implement similar functionality in pure Python. It uses four functions and their Python equivalents are: `Browser.SetZoomLevel`, `Browser.GetZoomLevel`, `cef.DpiAware.GetSystemDpi` and `cef.PostDelayedTask`.

See the C++ function source code here:

https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython/blob/6f5bf081fec19647e1860bb3e0f3638c02bb9d11/src/client_handler/dpi_aware.cpp#L163

Comment: Thank you, i will dig into the code. If i can do something i will post the solution!